# How to fix 'is assigned a value but never used" in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Whenever I use `useState` or a similar function with the same structure, I receive a lint error if I only need to use of the array functions, for example:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

If I only need to use `setSearchParams`, but not `searchParams`, lint will show an error that the first one is never used.

Replacing `searchParams` with null or undefined will throw other errors instead. Is there a way to fix this in the syntax? (Without changing lint configuratios)

Comment: Not sure why you are not using `searchParams`, but maybe you can replace it with `_`? `const [_, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();` since `_` is a convention to mean "I won't use this variable", or omit it completely

Comment: To be honest it's a little weird that you would need only the `setState` function but not the actual state value. However, if it is justified, you can write `const [, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();`. This way the first member of the array ( `searchParams` ) will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for! Yes it's temporary not using the first one

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use just `searchParams`, use this:

```js
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

If you want to use just `setSearchParams`, use this:

```js
const [, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
```